# C Provide float with binary bits produces the wrong number

Tags: c, floating-point, binary, hex

So, in C I am trying to give a floating point variable a number in binary bits (or hexadecimal digits) and then print it out, however it doesn't want to print the number I have calculated by hand or with an online converter.

```
float x = (float) 0b01000001110010000000000000000000;
```

or

```
float x = (float) 0x41C80000;
```

When printed out using

```
printf("%f", x);
```

produces results like this:

> 1103626240.000000

Instead of the expected 25, due to a sign bit of 0, exponent bit of 131, and a fraction of 1.5625.

Why is this, and how can I get the results I want?

Comment: Knowing nothing about C, I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that binary literals are of integral type, since that is the binary representation of the integral portion of the number your program outputs. This means your literal is of type int, which you are then casting to float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value `0x41C80000` in hex, is an integer that has the value `1103626240` in decimal. In your code, you are casting this value to a `float` which gives you this result:

```
x = 1103626240.000000
```

A solution for this can be made using a `union`:

```
union uint_to_float {
    unsigned int u;
    float f;
};

union uint_to_float u2f;
u2f.u = 0x41C80000;
printf("x = %f\n", u2f.f);
```

**EDIT:**
As mentioned by @chux, using `uint32_t` from `stdint.h`, instead of `unsigned int` is a better solution.

Comment: Needs to be `u2f.f` since `u2f` is not of type `float` or `double`. This currently prints `0.000000`.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Good yet disregards the usual suspects that can break the functionality: size of `unsigned` vs `float` (not so rare - a bit better to use `uint32_t`), mis-matched endian (rare), variant format of `float` (not so rare), padding (unheard of w/`unsigned`).

Comment: @chux yes choosing `uint32_t` would be better, but I thought of keeping it simple for the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Is there anyway to make C interpret the bits as float, or at least a simple cast to make it possible? I am assuming not otherwise that would be your answer...